# Operations on Python lists

Tags: python, list

I initiate a list as below -

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and assign two lists to it as below -

```
arrA = arr
arrB = arr
```

When I do **arrA.pop(0)**, why does it also pops the 0th element from **arrB** and **arr**? What is the logic behind this lists behavior in Python ?

Comment: ``print(id(arrA))`` & ``print(id(arrB))``  you will see both objects pointed to same ref.

Comment: Thanks, this clears the logic. any way to avoid it ?

Comment: Yes.. see the below answer, using deepcopy.

Answer (score 1):

because you just copy the address of the `arr` value (like pointers in C).

to independently copy the value to another list, you can use

```
arrA = arr.copy()
```

or

```
arrA = arr[:]
```

when you pop the arr, the value in arrA doesn't change.